# facebook iframe application ,with master page, doesn't firing OnSelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my radio button list:

```
   <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rdlTest" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdlTst_selectedChange">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList
```

this is the code behind:

```
protected void rdlTst_selectedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("hello");
    }
```

it's not firing the event for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You need to add AutoPostBack = "true" onto the definition of the RadioButtonList.

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rdlTest" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdlTst_selectedChange">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:RadioButtonList>
```